# Spring Security Logout no funciona

Tags: spring-security

Buenas, estoy usando Spring Security 4 en mi aplicacion y tengo la siguiente configuracion para el Login

```
http.authorizeRequests()
     //.antMatchers("/cliente/**").access("hasAnyAuthority('OPERADOR')")
             //.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).access("hasAnyAuthority('OPERADOR')")
     .antMatchers("/cliente/**").access("isAuthenticated()")
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).access("isAuthenticated()")                
             .antMatchers("resources/**").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("*/css/**").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("*/fonts/**").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("*/img/**").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("*/js/**").permitAll()

     .and().formLogin()
                  .loginPage("/auth/login").permitAll()
                  .defaultSuccessUrl("/cliente/crear")
                  .successHandler(new LoginSucessHandler())


                  .failureUrl("/auth/login?error=true").and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/auth/denied");
```

y para el logout tengo lo siguiente

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/logout"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logoutDo(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null){    
        HttpSession session= request.getSession(false);
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        //session= request.getSession(false);
        if(session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }
        for(Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) {
            cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        }            
        //new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
    }
    return "redirect:/auth/login";
}
```

Actualmente uso el control de numero de sesiones maxsession cuando entro con un usuario que tiene una sola sesion permitida, ingresa normal pero luego cierro sesion y vuelvo a intentar a entrar me sale el siguiente mensaje

> ```
> maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded
> ```

He leido en foros que se agrege lo siguiente

```
 <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

pero ya lo tengo agregado, segui las instrucciones [del siguiente link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557294/spring-security-logout-does-not-work-does-not-clear-security-context-and-authe)  pero me sigue pasando el problema,no se que podria estar faltan, tambien tengo en el evento del logout en link de 
`/auth/logout?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}"`, alguna solucion? les ha pasado el problema?

Comment: Hola Luigi Marquez. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Y mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tus preguntas. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema viene en que clearContext() no hace lo que crees que hace, prueba con:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null){    
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
    }
    return "redirect:/login?logout";// para redirigir a la pantalla de login
}
```

Comment: Cambie el codigo, pero sigue el mismo problema, gracias